# MySQL Rows Not being ignored

Tags: mysql

I have the result returning the way I want - I just want to ignore rows where **MPG_VALUE > 30** (*nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float*)

But my query returns all - and unwanted rows have NULL in **MPG_VALUE** column.

How can I return only rows where **MPG_VALUE > 30** ?

```
SELECT *, (SELECT PR_Basic + PR_VAT + PR_Delivery FROM nvdprices 
WHERE PR_Id = capder.cder_ID ORDER BY PR_EffectiveTo ASC LIMIT 1) as P11D,

(SELECT nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float FROM nvdtechnical 
 WHERE TECH_TechCode = '11' 
 AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Id = capder.cder_ID
 AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float > 30 
 LIMIT 1) as MPG_VALUE

from capmod 

JOIN capder ON capder.cder_modcode = capmod.cmod_code 
JOIN caprange ON capder.cder_rancode = caprange.cran_code 
JOIN capman ON caprange.cran_mantextcode = capman.cman_code 
JOIN nvdmodelyear ON capder.cder_ID = MY_Id 

AND nvdmodelyear.MY_EffectiveTo = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 

JOIN nvdtechnical ON nvdtechnical.TECH_Id = capder.cder_ID
JOIN nvddictionarytechnical ON nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = nvdtechnical.TECH_TechCode
JOIN nvddictionarycategory ON nvddictionarycategory.DC_CatCode = nvddictionarytechnical.DT_CatCode

AND nvddictionarycategory.DC_CatCode=4 
AND nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = 67
AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float >= '255' 

JOIN capfueltype ON capfueltype.cft_code = capder.cder_fueltype 
JOIN nvdbodystyle ON capmod.cmod_bodystyle = nvdbodystyle.bs_code 

WHERE caprange.cran_mantextcode='140' 
AND caprange.cran_code='522' 
AND capder.cder_fueltype='P' 
AND capder.cder_transmission='A' 
AND nvdbodystyle.bs_code='3' 
AND (cmod_discontinued=0 OR cmod_discontinued=2015) 
AND capman.cman_code IN ('1','140','164') 
AND caprange.cran_code IN ('924','126','147','955','965','661') 

ORDER BY P11D, capman.cman_name ASC, caprange.cran_name, capmod.cmod_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are doing a scalar query for the MPG Value. You are not really filtering which rows to show or hide, rather, you are showing all rows that has a value matched from your main query.

Imagine a left join, that is like what you are doing

```
SELECT nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float FROM nvdtechnical 
 WHERE TECH_TechCode = '11' 
 AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Id = capder.cder_ID
 **AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float > 30** 
 LIMIT 1
```

to properly filter the data, you must filter in once more outside it in your where condition:

the easiest way would be like this one.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *, (SELECT PR_Basic + PR_VAT + PR_Delivery FROM nvdprices 
WHERE PR_Id = capder.cder_ID ORDER BY PR_EffectiveTo ASC LIMIT 1) as P11D,

(SELECT nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float FROM nvdtechnical 
 WHERE TECH_TechCode = '11' 
 AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Id = capder.cder_ID
 AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float > 30
 LIMIT 1) as **MPG_VALUE**

from capmod 

JOIN capder ON capder.cder_modcode = capmod.cmod_code 
JOIN caprange ON capder.cder_rancode = caprange.cran_code 
JOIN capman ON caprange.cran_mantextcode = capman.cman_code 
JOIN nvdmodelyear ON capder.cder_ID = MY_Id 

AND nvdmodelyear.MY_EffectiveTo = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 

JOIN nvdtechnical ON nvdtechnical.TECH_Id = capder.cder_ID
JOIN nvddictionarytechnical ON nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = nvdtechnical.TECH_TechCode
JOIN nvddictionarycategory ON nvddictionarycategory.DC_CatCode = nvddictionarytechnical.DT_CatCode

AND nvddictionarycategory.DC_CatCode=4 
AND nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = 67
AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float >= '255' 

JOIN capfueltype ON capfueltype.cft_code = capder.cder_fueltype 
JOIN nvdbodystyle ON capmod.cmod_bodystyle = nvdbodystyle.bs_code 

WHERE caprange.cran_mantextcode='140' 
AND caprange.cran_code='522' 
AND capder.cder_fueltype='P' 
AND capder.cder_transmission='A' 
AND nvdbodystyle.bs_code='3' 
AND (cmod_discontinued=0 OR cmod_discontinued=2015) 
AND capman.cman_code IN ('1','140','164') 
AND caprange.cran_code IN ('924','126','147','955','965','661') 

ORDER BY P11D, capman.cman_name ASC, caprange.cran_name, capmod.cmod_name 
) x
WHERE x.MPG_VALUE IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that the x.MPG_VALUE which is filtered outside is your scalar query.

Edit: You can try other methods like, inner join.

```
SELECT *, (SELECT PR_Basic + PR_VAT + PR_Delivery FROM nvdprices 
WHERE PR_Id = capder.cder_ID ORDER BY PR_EffectiveTo ASC LIMIT 1) as P11D,
MPG_VALUE.TECH_Id
from capmod
JOIN capder ON capder.cder_modcode = capmod.cmod_code 
JOIN caprange ON capder.cder_rancode = caprange.cran_code 
JOIN capman ON caprange.cran_mantextcode = capman.cman_code 
JOIN nvdmodelyear ON capder.cder_ID = MY_Id 
AND nvdmodelyear.MY_EffectiveTo = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
JOIN nvdtechnical ON nvdtechnical.TECH_Id = capder.cder_ID
JOIN nvddictionarytechnical ON nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = nvdtechnical.TECH_TechCode
JOIN nvddictionarycategory ON nvddictionarycategory.DC_CatCode = nvddictionarytechnical.DT_CatCode
AND nvddictionarycategory.DC_CatCode=4 
AND nvddictionarytechnical.DT_TechCode = 67
AND nvdtechnical.TECH_Value_Float >= '255' 
JOIN capfueltype ON capfueltype.cft_code = capder.cder_fueltype 
JOIN nvdbodystyle ON capmod.cmod_bodystyle = nvdbodystyle.bs_code 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT TECH_Value_Float,TECH_Id
    FROM nvdtechnical 
    WHERE TECH_TechCode = '11' 
    AND TECH_Value_Float > 30
) MPG_VALUE
ON MPG_VALUE.TECH_Id = capder.cder_ID
WHERE caprange.cran_mantextcode='140' 
AND caprange.cran_code='522' 
AND capder.cder_fueltype='P' 
AND capder.cder_transmission='A' 
AND nvdbodystyle.bs_code='3' 
AND (cmod_discontinued=0 OR cmod_discontinued=2015) 
AND capman.cman_code IN ('1','140','164') 
AND caprange.cran_code IN ('924','126','147','955','965','661') 
ORDER BY P11D, capman.cman_name ASC, caprange.cran_name, capmod.cmod_name;
```

Comment: Just wondering @Arzgethalm... 
I expected to be able to simply say WHERE MPG_VALUE != NULL in the end. Is there any way to just use the MPG_VALUE - the way I had it? Without having to add the additional "SELECT *
FROM ()x" ?? Thanks : )

Comment: @Kreeverp Updated my answer, Yup, there are a number of methods available, it depends on you actually what you will use. But if you are trying to focus on performance and optimization. You can start by re organizing your query first. There are tons of other answers here that will tell you a better approach.

Comment: Also note that "!= NULL" will generally not give the results you want (it's always NULL, even if the comparison value is also NULL). To compare to null you must use "is NULL" or "is not NULL"

Comment: Hi @Arzgethalm and thanks again. The first example worked - but I could not get the second one to work. The main purpose for this whole attempt - is to add another query to the `TECH_Value_Float` as it is used for both MPG and CO2 values. The query is accurate - with either one - the problem for me, has been making the second MPG query